# Can I modify elements in iframes from the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have a page containing two separate iframes(header and navigation), which have some links inside. (I know it sucks. I have to do this, because the header and navigation are actually from another project)

When I click the links inside the iframes, only the relevant iframe changes. While what I want is that when I click the link, the whole page, namely the current window, changes to that new URL.

I know javascript injection is not possible and I can't append a <base target='_top'> into iframes' <head>.

Is there any way I can achieve what I want? Or if you have a better way other than <iframe>, please don't hesitate to tell me. I'm still a novice in Front-End engineering. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can´t you use PHP and include() or sth. like that?

Comment: I just re-read your question and you talk about injection. That makes me wonder; are you unable to change the framed page's source for some reason?

Comment: @Hemlock: Yes, that's right. If it's impossible to inject javascript into iframe, is there a better way to merge these parts other than iframe? What I want is that when I click the links in header and nav, the window directs to that URL.(While now, only the iframe changes.)

Comment: That depends. Are the frames on the same domain (including sub-domain and port)? Can you use a proxy to get them on the same domain?

Comment: @Hemlock Yes, they are on the same domain. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same domain? Go to town and inject a  tag, or modify all of the a tags to have a target. I can add more info on how to do it if needed.

**Edit**
Here's a jsbin page for completeness:
http://jsbin.com/osoji4/10

Comment: Since the header and nav area is from others' project, I can't contaminate their code with <code>target="_top"</code>. I'm wondering if there's another way to insert the header and nav area into my page, say Ajax. Thank you, Hemlock. You are such a nice guy.

Comment: Oh, that is completely opposite of what I was thinking. In that case doesn't Shadow Wizard's answer take care of your problem? Frame your project and put the target=_top attributes on all of your links? Requesting their code via ajax and injecting it into your pages would be a formidable challenge.

Comment: Oh, maybe I haven't clearly expressed my meaning. It's not my project that is framed. I have this HTML page, I put header & nav in respective div>iframe, and my project in a div#content. My original solution was trying to put the target attribute on all the links in iframe, but it turns out that I can't do it within this HTML page using either JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: Look at the code in that jsbin. I think it solves your problem. If it doesn't you'll have to try to post some code.

Comment: Yeah, the code in jsbin is exactly what I want. Thank you, Hemlock.

Answer (score 1):

Add `target="_top"` to the links in the frames, e.g.

```
<a href="SomePage.aspx" target="_top">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Similarly, in javascript you can do window.top.location.href = 'blah.aspx'

Comment: @Hemlock correct but why bother with JS when it's available in pure HTML? :)

Comment: We don't know what his links look like, maybe they are already firing JS. If that is the case, then it doesn't hurt to be complete.